# Python missing attributes/attributes not valid

Tags: python, maya

This is the code I am running but it says "These attributes  are not valid", how do I list attributes/transforms in my scene so I can list them properly. I tried using cmds.ls(type='transform') but it still doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
def changeXtransformVal(myList, percentage=2.0):

    """
    Changes the value of each transform in the scene by a percentange.
    Parameters:
    percentage - Percentange to change each transform's value. Default value is 1.
    Returns:
    Nothing.
    """
    # The ls command is the list command. It is used to list various nodes
    # in the current scene. You can also use it to list selected nodes.
    transformInScene = cmds.ls(type='transform')
    found = False
    for thisTransform in transformInScene:
        if thisTransform not in ['front','persp','side','top']:
            found = True
            break
        else:
             found = False
    if found == False:
           sphere1 = cmds.polySphere()[0]
           cmds.xform(sphere1, t = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
    transformInScene = cmds.ls(type='transform')
    # If there are no transforms in the scene, there is no point running this script
    if not transformInScene:
          raise RuntimeError, 'There are no transforms in the scene!'
    badAttrs = list()
    # Loop through each transform
    for thisTransform in transformInScene:
          if thisTransform not in ['front','persp','side','top']:
              allAttrs = cmds.listAttr(thisTransform, keyable=True, scalar=True)
          allAttrs = [ i for i in badAttrs if i != "visibility" ]
          print allAttrs     
    for attr in myList:
               if attr in allAttrs:
                   currentVal = cmds.getAttr( thisTransform + "." + attr )
                   newVal = currentVal * percentage
                   cmds.setAttr(thisTransform + "." + attr, newval)
                   print "Changed %s. %s from %s to %s" % (thisTransform,attr,currentVal,newVal)
               else:
                   badAttrs.append(attr)

    if badAttrs:
        print "These attributes %s are not valid" % str()

myList = ['sx', 'sy', 'tz', 'ty', 'tx']
changeXtransformVal(myList, percentage=2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple indentation error in several places. The last (on line 35):

```
for attr in myList:
```

the code is a level too low.  The code on line 31 > :

```
if thisTransform not in ['front','persp','side','top']:
     allAttrs = cmds.listAttr(thisTransform, keyable=True, scalar=True)
```

Should all be on the if level. Also this makes no sense:

```
allAttrs = [ i for i in badAttrs if i != "visibility" ]
```

is indented wrong all your code after that should be on the level of your if. Here's the central part written again:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
def changeXtransformVal(myList, percentage=2.0):
    transformInScene = [i for i in cmds.ls(type='transform') if i not in ['front','persp','side','top'] ]
    myList = [i for i in myList if i not in ['v','visibility']]
    for thisTransform in transformInScene:
        badAttrs = []
        for attr in myList:
            try:
                currentVal = cmds.getAttr( thisTransform + "." + attr )
                newVal = currentVal * percentage
                cmds.setAttr(thisTransform + "." + attr, newVal)
                print "Changed %s. %s from %s to %s" % (thisTransform,attr,currentVal,newVal)
            except TypeError:
                badAttrs.append(attr)
        if badAttrs:
            print "These attributes %s are not valid" % str(badAttrs)

myList = ['sx', 'sy', 'tz', 'ty', 'tx']
changeXtransformVal(myList, percentage=2.0)
```

Note the nesting is a bit too deep consider moving the looping of mattress into a function definition.